# Trying to use '.append' in my python code, but resulting in a continuous failure on editor. Seems to work perfectly on IDLE

Tags: python, list

I was trying to gather names of people using a list and a for loop. It isn't working on the editor, but seems to work on the IDLE perfectly.

Tried moving code around, but resulted in bigger failure.

Code:

```
for i in range(4):
        userName = input('What is your name: ')
        Names = []
        Names.append(userName)

print(Names)
```

Expected output:

```
What is your name: LOL
What is your name: BYE
What is your name: SIGH
What is your name: duh
['LOL', 'BYE', 'SIGH', 'duh']
```

Current output:

```
What is your name: IDK
What is your name: WHatsyours
What is your name: lol
What is your name: duh
['duh']
```

Comment: initialize Names outside loop;

Comment: Please add some `print` statements inside loop and try to debug it your own.

Comment: "It isn't working on the editor..." what editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the list only *once*, outside the loop. Otherwise, you'd be overwriting it at each iteration. Try this:

```
Names = []
for i in range(4):
    userName = input('What is your name: ')
    Names.append(userName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting your list each iteration. The following will work for you:

```
Names = []
for i in range(4):
    userName = input('What is your name: ')

    Names.append(userName)

print(Names)
```